# How can I add a specific char in a string?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

My code takes a string as input and I need to swap uppercase for lowercase. So far, it goes through a loop and it finds if char is between 'A' and 'Z'. If it is, it copies the char in another register and increment it by 32 (to get lowercase equivalent). Now I just need to reinsert it into the original string. How can I do that? I thought I could maybe load it into the original string but it gives me a segmentation fault.
Code:

```
/*
        This code takes an input string from user
        It replaces \n by NULL
        It switches everything to lowercase
        It prints the name and the counter
*/

.global _start

_start:

    MOV R0, #1          @ Write to console
    LDR R1, =prompt     @ Load string in R1
    MOV R2, #23         @ Load string length in R2
    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    SWI 0               @ Run write

    MOV R0, #0          @ Read from keyboard
    MOV R2, #20         @ Buffer size
    MOV R7, #3          @ Syscall for read
    LDR R1, =input      @ Store input in name
    SWI 0

    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    MOV R0, #1          @ Writing destination is stdout
    LDR R1, =newline    @ Set the string address to prompt
    MOV R2, #1          @ Size of newline
    SWI 0

/* Find end of string (20 chars or "\n") */

    LDR R1, =input      @ Load input address into R1
    MOV R2, #0          @ Start counter at 0
    
replaceLoop:
    LDRB R0, [R1], #1   @ Load in the byte at addr R1
    ADD R2, R2, #1      @ Increment counter
    CMP R2, #21         @ Have we read all 20 characters
    BGE replaceChar     @ If counter eq or greater than 20 replace char
    
    CMP R0, #10         @ Compare char to newline
    ADDNE R1, R1, #1    @ Increment addr, go to next char
    BNE replaceLoop     @ If its not equal restart loop
    
replaceChar:
    MOV R3, #0          @ put NULL in R3
    STRB R3, [R1]       @ put NULL at end of string
    
    SUB R0, R2, #1      @ Count how many chars (newline pos - 1)
    PUSH {R2}           @ Store size in stack


/* Replace uppercase by their lowercase equivalent */
    LDR R1, =input      @ Resetting R1 to make things easier
    MOV R2, #0          @ Counter at 0, need to know if char# < 21
    
caseLoop:
    LDRB R0, [R1], #1   @ Load char in R0
    
    ADD R2, R2, #1      @ Increment counter
    CMP R2, #21         @ Have we read all 20 characters
    BGE print_end       @ If counter eq or greater than 20 exit loop
    
    CMP R0, #65         @ Compare char to 'A'
    BLT caseLoop        @ If less than 'A' restart loop
    CMP R0, #90         @ Compare to 'Z'
    BGT caseLoop        @ If greater than 'Z' restart loop
    
    ADD R0, R0, #32     @ change 'A' to 'a'
    STRB R0, [R1, #-1]  @ Store new char in original string
    B caseLoop          @ restart loop
    
    /* Print input */
print_end:
    MOV R0, #1          @ Write to console
    POP {R2}            @ Get size back
    SUB R1, R1, R2      @ Reset R1 offset
    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    SWI 0               @ Execute WRITE
    
    PUSH {R2}           @ Take back R2 into stack
    
    MOV R0, #1          @ Writing destination is stdout
    LDR R1, =newline    @ Set the string address to prompt
    MOV R2, #1          @ Size of newline
    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    SWI 0
    
    MOV R0, #1          @ Writing destination is stdout
    POP {R1}            @ Set the string address to prompt
    MOV R2, #1          @ Size of newline
    MOV R7, #4          @ Syscall for write
    SWI 0
    
_exit:
    MOV     R7, #1
    SWI     0
    
.data

prompt:     .asciz "\nPlease enter a word : " @ 23
input:      .space 21
newline:    .asciz "\n"
```

Edit: I no longer have an error code, but the logic still isn't there. I'm getting gibberish when I reprint the word. It even stays if I rerun the code even if I input something completely different. I've updated the code.
Edit 2: Resetted R1's pointer, but it still prints gibberish. It now only works if the word is 5 character long for some reason.

Comment: `LDR R1, [R3, R2]` makes little sense. It's a load not a store. It's a word operation, not a byte. `R3` contains your char but you use it as an address. `R2` is the counter but that has nothing to do here. Since you loaded with `LDRB R0, [R1], #1` you should be able to write back simply with `STRB R3, [R1, #-1]`. PS: since you don't even need `R0` there is not much point in copying it to `R3` but that is of course allowed.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. My program now outputs gibberish. Would it be due to logic failure or does it still have to do with how I stored it? (I updated the code in main post)

Comment: Have you tried stepping it with a debugger?

Comment: We only see debuggers next week so I have no clue how to do it. That being said. It now works with 5 letters word (but not any other lengths). I have been messing around with it and I can't the problem.

Comment: Using a debugger is the first thing you should learn; it makes it possible to see what your code is doing, in terms of what each instruction is doing.  Just looking at the final result is much harder, and gives you not nearly enough information.  It's a waste of your time and everyone else's to not be using a debugger.

Comment: While waiting for you official debugger-related course, you could test the purely algorithmic part using this easy-to-use online [assembler/emulator/debugger](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm): instead of relying on inputs/ouputs, just assume the string to be processed is already in memory at 'input'. You will be able to execute the program step by step and see what in going on in both the registers and the memory. And the less code you have to debug, the better it is.

Comment: Running a minimal version of your code with the simulator with an hard-coded test vector (`input:      .asciz "THIS IS A TEST\n"`) results in "`this a test\n`" being located at `input` at the time the label `print_end` is being reached, which is fine I guess. That means the problem may be in the code responsible for printing the result.